# C# Download file - BADRESPONSE: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: c#

I am calling this direct method but I receive this error when I try to download the file (path is ok and tested):

```
[DirectMethod]
    public void downloadFile(string fname, string ftype)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
        String Header = "Attachment; Filename=" + fname;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", Header);
        System.IO.FileInfo Dfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("CopyFiles\\" + ftype + "\\"+ fname));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(Dfile.FullName);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

> BADRESPONSE: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just needed to flush() before WriteFile() :

```
[DirectMethod]
public void downloadFile(string fname, string ftype)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
    String Header = "Attachment; Filename=" + fname;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", Header);
    System.IO.FileInfo Dfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("CopyFiles\\" + ftype + "\\"+ fname));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(Dfile.FullName);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```